# How to center text in python 3 after an input()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I can't really find anything that really helps online so I thought I'd ask myself.  I have the following code:

```
username = input()
username = username.capitalize()
print("Hello " + username ) # I want this to be centered
```

I want the print statement to be centered on whatever console it is being ran on.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to this.

---

First, you need to get the console width. You do that with [`shutil.get_terminal_size`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.get_terminal_size).

Since it isn't always possible to get the console width—for that matter, there might not even *be* one (e.g., if your program's standard output is redirected to a file and doesn't even have a terminal), it will fall back to 80 columns (although you can override that if you want):

```
cols, rows = shutil.get_terminal_size()
```

---

Now you just [`center`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.center) the string in that width. The fact that the string includes user input doesn't matter. Once you concatenate `"Hello "` and `username`, you've got a `str` that works the same as any other string object. So:

```
print(("Hello " + username).center(cols))
```

---

If it's possible that the user's input will be too long to fit on one line, you want to wrap it first, then center the lines. You can use the [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) module for that:

```
for line in textwrap.wrap("Hello " + username, cols):
    print(line.center(cols))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `os.get_terminal_size().columns` to get the number of columns in the terminal and then print the necessary spaces to centralise your text:

```
import os
def print_centre(s):
    print(' ' * ((os.get_terminal_size().columns - len(s))//2) + s)
```

[image: hello there]

---

Some improvements (as pointed out by abarnert):

1. `shutil.get_terminal_size` is more reliable than `os.get_terminal_size`.
2. You can use `s.center(...)` for more readability.

Which gives a neater solution:

```
import shutil
def print_centre(s):
    print(s.center(shutil.get_terminal_size().columns))
```

Comment: As the docs for `os.get_terminal_size` explain, you should not use that function; use the one in `shutil`. This reads `COLUMNS` and `LINES` if they exist, falls back to `os.get_terminal_size` if they don't, and falls back to 80x24 if that doesn't work either.

Comment: Also, you don't need to manually center text by printing spaces. Just call the `center` method.